# Variable dependency expressed with matrix

Tags: excel, matrix, statistics, calculation

Let's say I have variables A and B, both are on a scale from 1 to 15. In order to combine the two, I have a matrix AB that gives me the value of the variable C (combination of A and B).

If I assume both variables A and B are proportionally combined, with a given weight *x*. Such that `A*x + B*(1-x) = C`. This relationship can be expressed using a matrix as well (assuming x = 0.25, and **I am rounding up all the numbers**):

[image]

Now let's say I have matrix AB but the weighting *x* is unknown. Is there a way to find or approximate *x*, considering the below AB matrix?

[image]

So far I have tried creating a dummy matrix AB' using the proxy weight *x'*, then subtracting matrices: AB - AB'. Then summing up absolute differences of all items and using Excel Solver to minimize it by modifying *x'* (with boundaries on *x'* [0.01:0.99]):

[image]
[image]

Also, I've tried to get more precise results by using a vector of *X'* of weights instead of single weight *x'*. This looks better and I can explain the relationship between variables A and B using min and max of this range:

[image]
[image]

Now the question here is there a more mathematical method to describe the relationship of the combination of A and B? Or maybe a more elegant solution?

The above is a good example of AB matrix. The below one doesn't have such a nice solution. You can also note that B axis is inverted and the C value resulting from combining A[15] and B[15] equals to 9, which is not explainable by `A*x + B*(1-x) = C`. Would be thankful for any suggestions!

[image]
[image]
[image]